# Google apps script regex matching nth occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

In this answer: [To exceed the ImportXML limit on Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014766/to-exceed-the-importxml-limit-on-google-spreadsheet?answertab=votes#48483734)

How would I match an nth occurrence? I tried including {5} in the script but it would give me an `#ERROR!`

This site doesn't exactly work with the author's example.
https://regex101.com/r/pzMw0A/3

The answer from the author `>(.*?%\s+APR)` only matches the first occurrence.

What I'm trying to do is to get `2.49%` from this page https://actorsfcu.com/loans/auto

Here is the google spreadsheet with the script loaded (A1 & A3):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D6Qf44kL6_x7Ippsj6OkePO_eDBVxkIsHr0iieI0ECY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try use the `g`flag to make it global and catch all occurences. Now if you wan't to use regex [here](https://github.com/google/re2) is the regex version that uses google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var value = html.match(new RegExp(/>(.*?%\s+APR)/, 'g')[indexOfValue];
```

put `g`as indicator argument, this flag will apply the regex even if a new line character occurs.

Comment: btw, looks like `=importRegex("https://actorsfcu.com/loans/auto",">(.*?%)\s+APR",3)` results in `>1.99% APR` I tried to just get the number from this result, it worked with the previous script but not with this change, do you know why?

Comment: I'll check and get back to you if I find the answer

Comment: @sojim Well it's normal to get that result what di you wanted `1,99`?

Comment: I got it with this, thank you! `\d\.(.*?%)(?=\s+APR)`