# Is there some kind of limit when using IMPORTXML?

Tags: google-sheets, xml-parsing, google-sheets-formula

In column A I have a list of URLs. In column B I have a formula `=IMPORTXML(A2, "//head/title")`. I would like to extract titles of all pages for which I have URLs.

For some URLs I got the data, for other I can see message Loading that on Hover shows "Error Loading data".

[image]

On one sheet I have about 500 URLs, and on another about 1100 URLs.

Why did IMPORTXML manage to fetch some data but not all? Is there some kind of query limit? If it is important I'm using company account (paid, not free Google account).

Comment: there was a limit of 50 importxml calls

Comment: You may want to check this: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97629/why-wont-importxml-work-on-this-sheet

Comment: Than you Gabriel. Yes, it seems that there is a limit but it is not clearly stated anywhere. The script from linked answer is working.

Comment: I've searched for that same code on SO, and I've found it in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014766/to-exceed-the-importxml-limit-on-google-spreadsheet. I'll mark my own question as a duplicate.