# How can I customize the existing script to import multiple values of identical regex paths

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I use the script from this post to import the value via a regex path
[To exceed the ImportXML limit on Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014766/to-exceed-the-importxml-limit-on-google-spreadsheet)

```
function importRegex(url, regexInput) {
  var output = '';
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();
    if (html.length && regexInput.length) {
      output = html.match(new RegExp(regexInput, 'i'))[1];
    }
  }
  // Grace period to not overload
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  return unescapeHTML(output);
}

var htmlEntities = {
  nbsp:  ' ',
  cent:  '¢',
  pound: '£',
  yen:   '¥',
  euro:  '€',
  copy:  '©',
  reg:   '®',
  lt:    '<',
  gt:    '>',
  mdash: '–',
  ndash: '-',
  quot:  '"',
  amp:   '&',
  apos:  '\''
};

function unescapeHTML(str) {
    return str.replace(/\&([^;]+);/g, function (entity, entityCode) {
        var match;

        if (entityCode in htmlEntities) {
            return htmlEntities[entityCode];
        } else if (match = entityCode.match(/^#x([\da-fA-F]+)$/)) {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match[1], 16));
        } else if (match = entityCode.match(/^#(\d+)$/)) {
            return String.fromCharCode(~~match[1]);
        } else {
            return entity;
        }
    });
};
```

The problem is that this way only one value is imported, e.g. only one value from H2, even if there are several H2 tags on the page.
How do I adjust the code to output all values that match the regex path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function importRegex(url, regexInput) {
  var output = [];
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();
    if (html.length && regexInput.length) {
      var results = html.matchAll(new RegExp(regexInput, 'ig'));
      for (result of results){
       output.push(result[1])
      }
    }
  }
  // Grace period to not overload
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  output = output.map(x => unescapeHTML(x));
  return output;
}
```

Note that the required changes are only to the `importRegex()` function but you still need to keep `htmlEntities` and `unescapeHTML()` as they were.

**Explanation:**

The original function uses [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) which returns only one result from the regex. If you want more results then you can use [`matchAll()`](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/library/string/matchall) and loop through the iterator to build the `output` array.

```
  var results = html.matchAll(new RegExp(regexInput, 'ig'));
    for (result of results){
      output.push(result[1])
    }
```

After that to run every element through the `unescapeHTML` function you can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
  output = output.map(x => unescapeHTML(x));
```

As a test we can try the following call to get the h2 headers from the Wikipedia [Soap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap) page:

```
=IMPORTREGEX("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap", "<h2><(?:.*?)>(.*?)<\/span>")
```

This will expand the array over however many rows are needed:

[image]

The tricky part is getting the regex right, but this will depend on the site that you want to scrape.